# What would be a regex to match all occurrences after =, space separated?

Tags: regex, go

I have `/components/component[name=fan/10 index=55]/cpu`

I want a `regex` that givens me `fan/10` and `55`.

I tried stuff like `=(.*)\s`, but doesn't work. But I'm guessing it has to be done using capturing groups (the () ) somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
=([^\]\s]+)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WU5RTQ/1)

**Details**

- `=` - an equals sign
- `([^\]\s]+)` - Capturing group 1: any 1 or more chars other than `]` and whitespace.

**[GO demo](https://play.golang.org/p/4tJcEUadGgC)**:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)


func main() {
    s := "/components/component[name=fan/10 index=55]/cpu"
    rx := regexp.MustCompile(`=([^\]\s]+)`)
    matches := rx.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
    for _, v := range matches {
        fmt.Println(v[1])   
    }
}
```

Output:

```
fan/10
55
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use something like this:

```
s := "/components/component[name=fan/10 index=55]/cpu"
re := regexp.MustCompile(`=([^\s\]]*)`)
matches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
fmt.Println(matches)
```

Result will be:

```
[[=fan/10 fan/10] [=55 55]]
```